# Fetching one item sequentially from the list by a generator method

Tags: python

Here is my `fetch_all_agents` method, is which considered to provide all of the agent coordinates, in one shot:

```
def fetch_all_agents(number_of_agents = None):

    agentList = []
    agentConfig = configparser.ConfigParser()

    agentConfig.readfp(open(r'SwarmSimulator\configFile.txt'))
    random_option = agentConfig.get('Agent Generation', "random_option")

    if(random_option == "True"):
        agentList = agentObj.generate_agents(number_of_agents)
    elif(random_option == "False"):
        with open(r"SwarmSimulator\agentListFile.txt") as f:

            tempList = [list(ast.literal_eval(line)) for line in f]

        pointObj = Point.Point()

        for innerList in tempList:
            pointObj.x = innerList[0]
            pointObj.y = innerList[1]

            agentObj = Agent.Agent(pointObj)

            agentList.append(agentObj)
    return agentList
```

I am going to plan the other method, let's name it `fetch_single_agent` to read one agent from the list, the one which the right agent held next to the last fetched one. It is reasonable to take a generator into account to hit this mark.

Would you please guide me to implement a generator-driven version for above method, in which, as I explained, one can fetch an agent from the list in an ordered manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `yield` the `agentObj`:

```
   for innerList in tempList:
        pointObj.x = innerList[0]
        pointObj.y = innerList[1]
        agentObj = Agent.Agent(pointObj)
        yield agentObj

agent_gen = fetch_all_agents(5)

for agent in agent_gen:  
   print(agent)
```

Or get one agent using next:

```
 agent_gen = fetch_all_agents(5)
 ag_1 = next(agent_gen)
```

Comment: Thank you... But shouldn't I check any situation, in which the list has been iterated, completely, and there is no more agent to be fetched?...

Comment: @Ordenador. when you have iterated over  `tempList` there will be no more  `agentObj's` to yield. Yielding means you can iterate getting an agent at a time instead of creating a full list